# Caching in React

Tags: reactjs, caching

In my react App I have a input element. **The search query should be memoized**, which means that **if the user has previously searched for 'John'** and the API has provided me valid results for that query, then **next time when the user types 'Joh'**, there should be **suggestion** for the user with the previously memoized values(in this case 'John' would be suggested).

I am new to react and am trying caching for the first time.I read a few articles but couldn't implement the desired functionality.

Answer (score 5):

You don't clarify which API you're using nor which stack; the solution would vary somewhat depending on if you are using XHR requests or something over GraphQL.

For an asynchronous XHR request to some backend API, I would do something like the example below.

#### Query the API for the search term

```
_queryUserXHR = (searchTxt) => {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: searchTxt,
    success: (data) => {
      this.setState({previousQueries: this.state.previousQueries.concat([searchTxt])
    }
  });
}
```

You would run this function whenever you want to do the check against your API. If the API can find the search string you query, then insert that data into a local `state` array variable (`previousQueries` in my example).

You can either return the data to be inserted from the database if there are unknowns to your view (e.g database id). Above I just insert the `searchTxt` which is what we send in to the function based on what the user typed in the input-field. The choice is yours here.

#### Get suggestions for previously searched terms

I would start by adding an input field that runs a function on the `onKeyPress` event:

```
<input type="text" onKeyPress={this._getSuggestions} />
```

then the function would be something like:

```
_getSuggestions = (e) => {
  let inputValue = e.target.value;
  let {previousQueries} = this.state;
  let results = [];
  previousQueries.forEach((q) => {
    if (q.toString().indexOf(inputValue)>-1) {
      result.push(a);
    }
  }
  this.setState({suggestions: results});
}
```

Then you can output `this.state.suggestions` somewhere and add behavior there. Perhaps some keyboard navigation or something. There are many different ways to implement how the results are displayed and how you would select one.

<sup>*Note: I haven't tested the code above*</sup>

Comment: I am using Github Search API and MERN stack.I tried the mentioned solution but it dint work for me

Comment: It requires some adjusting on your end to make it work. This isn't a full solution.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have somewhere a function that queries the server, such as

```
const queryServer = function(queryString) {
  /* access the server */
}
```

The trick would be to memorize this core function only, so that your UI thinks its actually accessing the server.

In javascript it is very easy to implement your own memorization decorator, but you could use existing ones. For example, `lru-memoize` looks popular on npm. You use it this way:

```
const memoize = require('lru-memoize')
const queryServer_memoized = memoize(100)(queryServer)
```

This code keeps in memory the last 100 request results. Next, in your code, you call `queryServer_memoized` instead of `queryServer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a memoization function:

```js
const memo = (callback) => {
  // We will save the key-value pairs in the following variable. It will be our cache storage
  const cache = new Map();
  return (...args) => {
    // The key will be used to identify the different arguments combination. Same arguments means same key
    const key = JSON.stringify(args);
    // If the cache storage has the key we are looking for, return the previously stored value
    if (cache.has(key)) return cache.get(key);
    // If the key is new, call the function (in this case fetch)
    const value = callback(...args);
    // And save the new key-value pair to the cache
    cache.set(key, value);
    return value;
  };
};

const memoizedFetch = memo(fetch);
```

This `memo` function will act like a key-value cache. If the params (in our case the URL) of the function (`fetch`) are the same, the function will not be executed. Instead, the previous result will be returned.

So you can just use this memoized version `memoizedFetch`  in your `useEffect` to make sure network request are not repeated for that particular petition.

For example you can do:

```js
// Place this outside your react element
const memoizedFetchJson = memo((...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json()));
```

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    memoizedFetchJson(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}/`)
      .then(response => {
        setPokemonData(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [pokemon]);
```

**[Demo integrated in React](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-mayer-n6dcj?file=/src/App.js)**