# Cache the value of a method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I'am working on a React project in which I can call an API which returns a list of user data, for example, something like this:

```
[{id:1,name:"Lukas",age:22...},{id:2,name:"Martha",age:32...},...,{id:200,name:"Joe",age:26...}]
```

The data is then sent as gridData in Kendo, so the grid is filled with data, and when you click on a row in the grid (one row = one user), you go to other component which gives you details about that user, etc. When I go back on the main component, the component is rendered again and the API that returns user data is called again.

Is it possible for that API to be called only once, in the beggining, and store that value somewhere? Bcz it takes a few seconds everytime I go back to that page for that API to be called/for it to respond. I want it to be called the first time user gets in the main component and then store that value somewhere so that the data is alway there and by that avoid calling the same API for x amount of times.

Comment: store `data` to local storage then each time you back check first in localStorage, if not get data then call api otherwise use fetched data. `but i best suggest you to use state management tools or react context api`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caching in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226228/caching-in-react)